# I'm Trying To Activate doSearch() via onClick

Tags: javascript

I've been on this code for the better part of about an hour (after typing the code) trying to figure out why my doSearch() command in my script doesn't want to activate. Any help you guys can offer would be appreciated.

Here's the script I've got:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    function doSearch() {
        var selectedItem = document.searchForm.engines
            .selectedIndex;
        if (selectedItem == -1)
            window.alert("You must select a
                search engine.");
        else
            location.href = document.searchForm.engines
               .option[selectedItem].value
               + document.searchForm.searchTerm.value;
    }
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

...And here is the button command I've got:

```
    <input type = "button" value="Search" 
    onclick = "doSearch()" /></p>
```

Is there something I have missed? :/

Comment: Needs clarification.  Do you receive any JavasScript error on the page?  Are you sure the doSearch function is not being invoked?

Comment: That's the thing... nothing comes up to indicate that there's any sort of error. And I don't really know whether or not the doSearch is invoked, because the Search button I created and (supposedly) linked to the doSearch function does nothing when I click on it. It's confusing me to no end.

Comment: Well, there are plenty of good Javascript debuggers to help, but I don't know what your setup/testing environment is.  A low level way to test would be to add an alert as the first line of doSearch.  That way you'd at least know if the function was being called, and if so debug the inner code.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah. You've missed return false; in your onclick event

```
<input type = "button" value="Search" 
onclick = "doSearch();return false" /></p>
```

without it, form has been submitted instead

Also you need to escape that new line in your alert

So

```
window.alert("You must select a
            search engine.");
```

becomes

```
window.alert("You must select a\
            search engine.");
```

Comment: Fixed those things, but the button still does not take me to the search engine. Anything else?

Comment: @Matt so your last line is probably wrong. Try to debug/alert result of it

Comment: Got an update: I finally managed to get the search button to work... the problem now is that it will just go to the search engine's page, and the value I'm trying to search isn't carrying over. Also, my window.alert isn't coming up when I don't type anything on the search bar.

Comment: @MattVogler: try just `alert("test")`

Comment: It did nothing... the main thing I am looking for is to be able to get the page to search the value that I put into the text block... so far, all it does is take me to the main page of the search engine, not showing any sign of me typing anything into the search block.

Comment: @Matt I have no idea why it doesn't work, but I'd think that your first question (original one), is solved. Open a new question for this specific case if you want